# Unable to open Content.mgcb in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, monogame, content-pipeline

I'm attempting to make my first Monogame project, and I want to add some graphic assets to it. I tried double-clicking the Content.mgcb file in the Solution Explorer window, but nothing happens.

Tried using the "Open with..." option to specifically select MGCB Editor. It already has that set as default, but even then, nothing happens.

I looked to see if the editor is indeed installed, and there is indeed a file named mgcb-editor in C:/Users/(my username)/.dotnet/tools. Double-clicking that file in the file window briefly brings up a window, but it quits immediately.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11. My Monogame version is 3.8.1.303.

Comment: have you tried following the instructions here https://docs.monogame.net/articles/tools/mgcb_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

As suggested by tval, you may be able to open the MonoGame Content Builder (MGCB) Editor via the command line as described at https://docs.monogame.net/articles/tools/mgcb_editor.html:

1. Make sure you've installed the VS extension *MonoGame Framework C# project template*
2. Open the terminal
3. Go to the project's root directory (using `cd`)
4. Launch the editor with `dotnet mgcb-editor`

Comment: I also need to launch using dotnet mgcb-editor ./Content/Content.mgcb